# How to calculate Adaptive gradient?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, optimization, gradient-descent, facial-recognition

In the [FaceNet paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.03832.pdf) there mentions an gradient algorithm called 'AdaGrad'(Adaptive Gradient) referenced to [this paper](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume12/duchi11a/duchi11a.pdf) which has apparently been used to calculate the gradient of the Triplet Loss function. After referring to the paper also I find it hard to understand how to calculate this adaptive gradient.

Any ideas regarding this matter? Would love to hear any explanations or ideas towards understanding this concept.

Thank you.